# Is there a way to see how much data was processed by a query run by a BigQuery user?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, usage-statistics

We have a project which is accessed by multiple users. Is there a way to see how much data is being processed by queries run by each of these users?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Jobs: list API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list)
You can retrieve all jobs run in given project by all users including those that are query.
In Response you should look for `totalBytesProcessed` , `totalBytesBilled` and `billingTier` as well as `user_email`

As an option you can consider using [Analyzing Audit Logs Using BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs)

Answer (score 0):

The **Query Validator** in the BigQuery Web UI also shows how many bytes will be / are processed. It is located at the top right of the window.

[image]